# Transfer execution to another javascript file from one javascript file

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to use webAPIs in javascript by implementing a dictionary api. I want to get input in variable `word` from the popup of the chrome extension using the file `popup.js`.

**Problem:** I want to store this `word` and pass it to another file `script.js` which contains the API call to search for the definition of this word and return it back to the `extension.js` file to display it back in the popup. How to implement this?

What I looked up was to use global variables by calling the file containing the declaration of the global variables ie. first `extension.js`, somehow transfering its execution to `script.js` and then returning the result back to `extension.js`. How to transfer this execution? Or is there a cleaner way of doing this? Also, is there a better way than using global variables to pass info between two javascript files.

These are the codes, I have written so far-

popup.html

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/extension.js"></script>
....
```

scripts.js

```
var url = 'http://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/entries?headword=' + word;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('accept', "application/json");

request.onload = function() {
    //Begin accessing JSON data here

    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    definition = data.results[0].senses[0].definition;
    definition = definition.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + definition.substr(1);
    console.log(definition);
}

request.send();
```

extension.js

```
var word, definition;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = "Extension loaded";
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');

    searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $('#status').html(definition);

        var word = $('#textInput').val();
        if(!word){
            $('#status').html("Please enter a word");
            return;
        }
    })

    addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $('#status').html('The word is added to the list');
    })
})
```

Anybody willing to give any advice would be very helpful. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use functions.

Comment: So I should enclose everything in `script.js` in a function and call it. Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: Also, are the "content_scripts": [{js: "scripts/script.js"}] of any help here? I don't quite understand what they are used for.

Comment: you can use module.exports to export your variable. Store the response in an exported variable, then import this variable in the wished file and use it

Comment: Are you writing a web page or a Chrome extension?

Comment: @HoCo_: He isn't writing Node or CommonJS.

Comment: @SLaks A chrome extension

Comment: @noogui I think you have accidentally posted the link of this webpage only

Comment: Can you try if [injecting scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) works for you? Also kindly check this [google forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/mSFjt0Lqz94).

Comment: @SLaks Using functions create another problem. The function returns back too fast to get the definition from the API call. Asynchronous use of `request.open('GET', url, false)` is deprecated. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use callbacks or promises.